# Update values of column conditionally dependent on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
  name origin delta
0 foo  raw_x   3
1 foo  raw_y   3
2 bar  raw_z   4
3 bar  raw_z   4
4 foobar raw_a  1
5 foobar raw_b  1
```

In the rows where `name = bar` the `origin` values are same so I can drop duplicates. But in rows where `name = foo`, the `origin` values are different. I want to modify/update the values in the same dataframe as below,

```
foo -> foo_x where raw_x
foo -> foo_y where raw_y
foobar -> foobar_a where raw_a
foobar -> foobar_b where raw_b
```

Name check like `if name == 'foo'` isn't possible, so we'll have to go by values that are the same in `name` column. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df['name'] = (
    df.groupby('name', sort=False)
    .apply(
        lambda x: x['name'] + '_' + x['origin'].str.rsplit('_', 1).str[1]
        if x['origin'].nunique() > 1
        else
        x['name']
    ).values
)
```

Complete example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'foo', 1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: 'bar', 4: 'foobar', 5: 'foobar'},
                   'origin': {0: 'raw_x',
                              1: 'raw_y',
                              2: 'raw_z',
                              3: 'raw_z',
                              4: 'raw_a',
                              5: 'raw_b'},
                   'delta': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 1, 5: 1}})

df['name'] = (
    df.groupby('name', sort=False)
    .apply(
        lambda x: x['name'] + '_' + x['origin'].str.rsplit('_', 1).str[1]
        if x['origin'].nunique() > 1
        else
        x['name']
    ).values
)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
       name origin  delta
0     foo_x  raw_x      3
1     foo_y  raw_y      3
2       bar  raw_z      4
3       bar  raw_z      4
4  foobar_a  raw_a      1
5  foobar_b  raw_b      1
```